# AppleScript text delimiters in objective c

Tags: objective-c, applescript

Is there an objective c version of text delimiters??

Here's the applescript code:

```
set oldDelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "Jarvis>"
set charliePlainOutput to (what ever needs to be parsed)
set charlieUnmoddedOutput to last text item of charliePlainOutput
set charlieOutputFiltered to text item 1 of charlieUnmoddedOutput
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "[Jarvis]"
set charlieOutputLast to text item 1 of charlieOutputFiltered
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "["
set charlieOutput to text item 1 of charlieOutputLast

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelim
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the intended input and output of your example?  That might help us come up with a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSString method `componentsSeparatedByString:` will do basically the same thing as `text items` in Applescript.  You can call than, then access objects from the array to get the substrings.  This example grabs all the text after the last occurrence of "Jarvis>" in the original string:

```
NSString* originalString; //comes from somewhere
NSArray* substrings = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@"Jarvis>"];
NSString* lastSubstring = [substrings lastObject];
```

However, if you just want to grab a substring off the front or the back of an existing string, take a look at `rangeOfString:`, `substringToIndex:`, and `substringFromIndex:`. You would first use `rangeOfString:` to find the string you want to separate by, then one of the substring methods to grab the actual text you want.  This is somewhat more efficient that `componentsSeparatedByString:` if you only want to access a single substring, rather than every single substring separated by your text delimiter.  This example grabs all the text before the first occurrence of "[Jarvis]" in the original string:

```
NSRange jarvisRange = [originalString rangeOfString:@"[Jarvis]"];
NSString* substring = [originalString substringToIndex:jarvisRange.location];
```

You can also use `rangeOfString:options:` passing in `NSBackwardsSearch` to the options parameter if you want to search from the end of the string rather than the front.